# Read row by row vb.net

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, row

I need to read row by row in  a column in a table then I need to store this then call procedure to insert data to a different column using vb.net.

I have already create the DB connection and I know how to call the procedure 
but I'm not sure of how to read in the loop and then to assign it to a variable to call it in the store procedure.

```
    Dim drDocs As SqlClient.SqlDataReader
    Dim cmdDocs As SqlClient.SqlCommand
    Dim Doc As Long
    Dim l As Long
    Using conn As New SqlConnection(DBpath)

        cmdDocs = New SqlClient.SqlCommand("Select (RecordID) from DocID", conn)
        drDocs = cmdDocs.ExecuteReader

        Do While drDocs.Read
           'need it read each row in that field and hold value'

        Loop
        drDocs.Close()
        cmdDocs.Dispose()



        If Doc Then


            cmdDocs = New SqlClient.SqlCommand("Insert_Doc", conn)

            cmdDocs.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

            cmdDocs.Parameters.Add("path", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value =need to put hold value from reading that cloumn row by row


            End If
        End If
```

Comment: `Select Max(RecordID) from DocID` will always return only 1 row. You know that right?

Comment: So how do I make it loop through the rows to get the value then use it to store so that call procedure can call it

Answer (score 0):

The code you've provided actually works now. It is as Juergen D says, sql functions like Max(), min() and using Limit will only return 1/certain number of rows based on their conditions.

if I may, just use this SQL command

```
    "select `RecordID` from DocID asc;"
```

If you want it in descending format, use desc instead

...now reading further, I realize that what you want to do is to store the results, then loop again through it so that you can do an sql command with it, correct? what you can do then is to pass the SQL results to a container (I use datagridviews) then loop through the container.